# Why does every digital camera save photos in a directory called DCIM?

Tags: terminology, digital, storage

It seems like every digital camera that I have ever used creates a folder called **DCIM** on its removable storage to save photographs into. Can anyone tell me what this name (DCIM) stands for (if anything) and/or explain the reason for this convention?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**DCIM** is short for **Digital Camera IMages** and is part of the industry standard outlined by the [Design rule for Camera File system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system). This standard was adopted as the de facto standard for storing digital image and sound files in memory devices by the digital camera industry to insure interoperability from one brand to the next.

From wikipedia:

> Design rule for Camera File system (DCF) is a JEITA specification (number CP-3461) which defines a file system for digital cameras, including the directory structure, file naming method, character set, file format, and metadata format. It is currently the de facto industry standard for digital still cameras. The file format of DCF conforms to the Exif specification, but the DCF specification also allows use of any other file formats.