# Damaged CR3 files saved by Canon M50 and then saved again correctly

Tags: raw, data-corruption, canon-m

While importing photos to Lightroom I got a somewhat worrying message that some of my photos can’t be imported as the file is damaged. Upon closer inspection, I have noticed that indeed several CR3 files were not fully saved (the file size was a fraction of the expected file size). Luckily they were all saved again with ‘-2’ in the file name.

[image]

Example:
IMG_2281.CR3 is only 9MB in size but then I have IMG_2281-2.CR3 which is a correctly saved file. The corresponding JPG files were saved only once and they were all not damaged.

Did anyone experience similar issue? What might be causing this behaviour, can it be the sign that the SD card is about to die (it’s only 4 months old) since the camera clearly was able to re-save the file?

**Edit:**

It is impossible for me now to check what was actually on the SD card - it was formated a few times since. I have copied the content of the card to my computer (macOS) simply by dragging them across. I only noticed this issue while importing them to Lightroom a few days later.

Comment: Are the "-2" files on the memory card itself? Or only on the drive to which you imported? It should not be possible for the camera to append a file name with "-2" as it violates the [Design Rule for Camera File System (DCF)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/46387/15871).

Comment: How, specifically, did you import the images? Via Canon's EOS Utility with the card in the camera and the camera connected to the computer via USB? Via a card reader? Some other method?

Comment: @MichaelC excellent question, I have updated my question. I used a built-in card reader in my MBP and just dragged files across.

Comment: did you import using "copy" and target and source folders the same?

Comment: @ths Nope, I imported using 'add' as files were already copied from the card to the right location on the disk.