# Which files on SD card are created by GoPro?

Tags: gopro

I have a GoPro Hero 5. I used one of my micro SD cards in it for a while and now I am using the card in another device. Every time I plug it in my computer, it recognizes it as a GoPro device and opens up GoPro Quik and tries to import new GoPro files from the card (which there aren't any). I have some files from my new device (DSLR camera) on this card already, therefore I don't want to format the card. Does anyone know which files should I delete for the Quik to stop recognizing this card as a GoPro Device?

[image: SD Card contents]

[image: Quik prompts no files to import]

Comment: It may well be that Quik is just detecting the DCIM folder is there.  I have an app from three cameras ago that autostarts any time I insert a memory card from a camera of any brand.

Comment: Could be. But as you can see in the screenshot it recognizes the card as HERO5 BLACK. That name has to be stored somewhere in one of the files.

Comment: @iamalminko Not necessarily. It could be that when you installed GoPro Quick on your computer it has a process that runs in the background opens the GoPro Quick screen anytime you connect a card with a DCIM folder on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Import the existing photos from the card on computer and format the card on your new device. This is usual practice when you use old card on new device. BTW after each import also format the card, this can save you from some problems in the future (if only delete the images).

And my humble advice will be not to use MicroSD cards on camera which support SD cards.

Comment: That makes the most sense. I will transfer all the media to the computer and then format the card in the new device.

Comment: @iamalminko, if you are happy with one of the answers feel free to accept it as answer of your question.

Answer (score 6):

The way to solve this (IMO) is not to mess with the SD card, but to stop the Quik application from running in the background, monitoring every card you insert, and slowing down your computer. (I guess this kind of bloatware is useful for the tech-illiterate, but it bugs old-school people like me.)

Click the "cog" near the top right of the Quik application, and deselect the option "Automatically launch Quik when camera is connected."

Also, I agree with Romeo - you should transfer your images/files to more reliable storage and format the SD card. I personally would never insert the same SD card into different imaging devices without formatting in between.

Comment: I actually like that it starts and imports the files from GoPro when I connect it either via USB or just insert the card in the card reader port. The problem is it opens up when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Recorded images from ***ALL*** camera devices should be in the [DCIM](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46386/15871)¹ folder that appears at the root level of the card.

If you're lucky, your different devices will have created different subfolders within the DCIM folder. Otherwise the images could be intermingled together.

That's just one of several reasons why you should **always offload all data on a flash memory card before formatting it in the new device** whenever you plan to save photos from the new device on it. Each imaging device should be compliant with the Design rule for Camera File system standard, but there is enough leeway within that standard to allow for different subfolder structures within the DCIM folder.

<sub>¹ **DCIM** is short for **Digital Camera IMages** and is part of the industry standard outlined by the [Design rule for Camera File system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system). This standard was adopted as the de facto standard for storing digital image and sound files in memory devices by the digital camera industry to insure interoperability from one brand to the next.</sub>

<sub>From wikipedia:</sub>

<sub>> Design rule for Camera File system (DCF) is a JEITA specification (number CP-3461) which defines a file system for digital cameras, including the directory structure, file naming method, character set, file format, and metadata format. It is currently the de facto industry standard for digital still cameras. The file format of DCF conforms to the Exif specification, but the DCF specification also allows use of any other file formats.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your input. In my case, two devices created their own subfolders so no problem there. I did not test if Quik reacts solely to DCIM folder existence, but as you can see in the screenshot, it recognizes the card as a HERO5 BLACK. This means that there is some GoPro generated file there that provides this string to Quik