# Photo filename convention: why not including time?

Tags: file-management, filenames

Filenames of photos stored on a camera's memory card follow the [Design rules for Camera Files systems](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-009-2010_E.pdf). They are merely counters with a prefix, e.g. DSC_, DSCF_, IMG_, ... and files are stored in a folder with a prefix as well, see also [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system).

I am not aware of any camera manufacturer including time stamps in the filenames. 
It would be rather convenient to be able to identify photos by a unique filename, ex DSCF_01012017_120302.jpg taken on Jan. the 1st 2017 at 12:03:02; rather than DSCF_12345.jpg, given the file name counter can be reset, and has no mnemonic indication of the file's content. If photos are shot at high burst rate (more than 1/second), then one could simply add a millisecond time-stamp or use a 2 letters coding.

One reason I can foresee for not using timestamps is that the file name can be long; but this can be solved by removing for example the date (day, month, year) from the name and storing files in folders with the date in their names.

Is there any specific reason not to use time stamps in photo filenames stored on memory cards?

**Edit**:

When asking my question, I hadn't found any similar one nor had SE suggested one, but here is a discussion on the topic:
[Why don't most cameras store filenames based on date and time?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/37820/61932) and a [good answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/37831/61932).